# why calloc pointer type is void *?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I reading a C book. but can't understand sentence that is

If the call calloc is successful,  pointer of type void* that points to the base of the array in memory is returned;

Here, if pointer of type void* that points to the base of the array in memory, then array[0] has type of void??

I want know what is mean...

Thank you guys read my question I hope receive answer!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14033412/951890

Comment: You would convert the `void *` to some other pointer type before writing `[0]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see how it's tempting to think that since `int *` points to `int`, then `void *` should point to `void`. But that's not the case. There's really no useful relationship between `void *` and `void` so it's best to think of them as separate concepts.

`void *` in C means a pointer that points to an object of unspecified type. You can think of it as the C analogue of Java `Object` if you're familiar with that.

`void *` has the following properties:

- Any pointer type can be converted to and from `void *`, i.e. `void *` is large enough to hold any pointer, even on machines where pointers to different types can have different size.
- Conversion between `void *` and other pointer types is implicit, you don't have to do an explicit cast.
- It's not permitted to de-reference `void *`, i.e. we must cast it to a concrete pointer type before accessing the memory it points to.
- You can't do address arithmetic on a `void *` in Standard C, though GCC allows you to do it as a documented extension.

`void *` is the type of choice for a function that needs to handle arbitrary data, like `calloc()`.

Answer (score 4):

`calloc` returns `void*` since:

1. `calloc` can be used to allocate memory for any type of object.
2. a `void*` can be implicitly cast to other pointer types.

If you use:

```
void* ptr = calloc(...);
```

it is valid but you can't use `*ptr`. A `void*` is not dereferenceable The pointer has to be cast to some other type to be dereferenced. E.g.

```
char* cptr = ptr;
*cptr = 'a';
```